# How to reset running total for a column if null is present?

Tags: mysql, sql, data-analysis

I have a table as below

| Customer | Start_Date_of_Month | Sales_order_count | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/06/2022 | 3 | null |
| B | 01/07/2022 | 2 | null |
| A | 01/07/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 01/08/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 01/08/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 01/09/2022 | 3 | null |
| B | 01/09/2022 | 1 | null |
| A | 01/10/2022 | 1 | null |
| B | 01/10/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 01/11/2022 | 0 | 1 |

I'm trying to calculate the running total of Value column with respect to Customer and by Start_Date _of_Month in ascending order. If null is present in the Value column, the running total has to be reset

The output would be like

| Customer | Start_Date_of_Month | Sales_order_count | Running_Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/06/2022 | 3 | null |
| A | 01/07/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 01/08/2022 | 0 | 2 |
| A | 01/09/2022 | 3 | null |
| A | 01/10/2022 | 1 | null |
| A | 01/11/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 01/07/2022 | 2 | null |
| B | 01/08/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 01/09/2022 | 1 | null |
| B | 01/10/2022 | 0 | 1 |

Thanks in Advance

Comment: which version of mysql ar you using ?

Comment: @AmitVerma I'm using an application called Zoho Analytics which have feature to write SQL dailect. This app supports  MySQL dailects, may be some functions might not be supported. If you have any idea how to achieve this, please share. I'll try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define groups for each customer whenever a null value is found, then use the running sum partitioned by these groups, try the following for MySQL 8+:

```
select Customer, Start_Date_of_Month, Sales_order_count,
  sum(Value) over (partition by Customer, grp order by Start_Date_of_Month) Running_Total
from
(
  select *,
    sum(value is null) over (partition by Customer order by Start_Date_of_Month) grp
  from table_name
) T
order by Customer, Start_Date_of_Month
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/7MnpytTa)